# PushPromise in HttpListenerResponse

Tags: c#, http2, httplistener

our web server is based on `System.Net.HttpListener`. The HttpListener is already able to handle HTTP/2 requests. Now I want to use new features like [Server Push](http://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#PushResources), but the [PushPromise](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn823340(v=vs.110).aspx) method is only available at `HttpResponse` and **not** at `HttpListenerResponse`.

Now I ask myself ...

- Is HttpListener dead? Can I expect HttpListener will be further developed?
- Are there better alternatives to HttpListener?
- Are there any workarounds to use new HTTP/2 features?